# list.files() displays all but four files in a directory

Tags: r

I'm using list.files() in R to get a list of gene expression data files to run through a parsing function. For some reason, list.files() shows all but the four most recent additions to the directory. I've tried using file.exist() on the four files using the same file path, which returns TRUE, as shown here (the actual file path is different, I just don't want to post proprietary stuff since I work in a lab):

```
filepath = system.file("my/file/path")
list.files(filepath, all.files=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)  # returns all but 4 files
file.exists(paste0(filepath, "/file_in_question"))  # returns TRUE
```

I've checked the directory visually as well and the files are all there and have the correct read/write permissions. Since I'm using the same filepath variable in list.files() and file.exists(), I know it's not a file path issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Apparently this is a bigger issue, since I can't see the files in the terminal using `ls`, although I can with `ls -thor`. Will update if I find a solution.

Comment: What is the pattern of these file names? Can you see them in the Terminal/CMD?

Comment: The pattern is runname00_graft.genes.tpm_tracking, with the number after the runname going from 01-100. I just checked and I actually cannot see them in the terminal.

Comment: Might be hard to debug over the internet in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I'm not finding any other people who've had the same problem. I think the issue might occur when I copy the files from the directory where they're originally outputted to the directory I'm referencing in R.

Comment: You can see them via GUI? Is the GUI directory different from the one you `ls` at the Terminal?

Comment: I can see them via GUI in the same directory. I can't see them using `ls` but I can using `ls -thor` and it is possible to view the files themselves using `less filename`.

Answer (score 0):

I realized just now that the problem is not that the files couldn't be read in, I was just looking in the wrong place. The most recent file was runnname100, which I expected to see right after runname99. However, R listed runname100 right in between runname10 and runname11. I will be adding a line or two to my script to reorder numerically so that the output isn't also ordered in such a stupid way.